# Prepare for segue not getting called in UITabbarController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have gone through all the other posts about this topic but they don't seem to help me.

I have a UITabBarController that is launching two tabs. I want to pass data collected in tab1 to the UITabBar ViewController. I am trying to use delegete protocol for this but I am having trouble setting the delegate variable in the sending ViewController. The prepare for segue never gets called. I cannot even cycle through the viewcontrollers of the tabs inside the ViewDidLoad() of the Tabbar controller as they are not created yet and so nil.

I have used delegates before and it seems rather straightforward. Does it matter that I am using it in a Tabbar?

When I run the code the viewDidLoad() in TabBarViewController is called but not the preparefor segue.

The IBAction donePressed in the MeViewController is called but the delegate is not called as its not set.

Here is the code --

```
protocol DetailsDelegate: class {
    func myDetailsGathered( myDetails: MyDetails )
}

/// RECEIVING VIEW CONTROLLER

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, DetailsDelegate
{

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        print("prepare for segue called\n");

        if let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? MeViewController
        {
            destinationViewController.delegate = self
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        print("ViewDidLoad Called \n")
    }

    func myDetailsGathered(myDetails: MyDetails)
    {
        self.myDetails = myDetails
        print("My details gathered \n")
    }

}

---------------
/// SENDING VIEW CONTROLLER

class MeViewController: UIViewController
{
    weak var delegate: DetailsDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    // I have UIButton in the view and this is invoked when its pressed. 
    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any)
    {
        var infoToPass = MyDetails()

        print("looks like we are done")
        delegate?.myDetailsGathered(infoToPass: myDetails)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` is called when you perform a segue. Which you don´t do and that´s why it does not get called.

> A segue defines a transition between two view controllers in your
>   app’s storyboard file.

You should use a `singleton` class to store variables and access them between different controllers. You declare one like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
    var name = ""
}
```

Assign to Singleton:

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.name = "Some name"
```

To read from it from whatever controller:

```
let name = Singleton.sharedInstance.name
```

Comment: I thought prepareForSegue is part of the initialization of the ViewController. Great to know. If I don't want to use a singleton, how do I initialize the delegate?

Comment: @SFlow, it´s not. It notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed.

Comment: Is there another way to initialize the delegate without using segues? All I want to do is initialize the delegate and don't care about using segues.

Comment: No... As I wrote in my previous comment the `prepareForSegue` notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed, nothing else. Do it as I suggested in my post, it´s a clean way to handle it.

Comment: It solves it one way I guess but I did not want to use a singleton but instead wanted to use a delegate. I am still trying to figure it out. Couldn't get to the code to sit on it. If I cannot find one I will use Singleton and accept your answer.

Comment: is my question bad or wrong to begin with? Why do you think its downvoted?

Comment: @SFlow, using a delegate in this case is wrong. That´s why I provided the answer I did for you.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, why do you want your tabbarController to receive some info/data though?

> The prepare for segue never gets called.

`prepareForSegue` method will be invoked right after the `performSegue`. So where's your `performSegue` method? Or are you sure that that kind of `segue` going to `MeViewController` is being performed?

One more option you have is to use `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: I want to send it so that it can do other operations on it and in turn send it to the second tab. I see that I don't understand segues properly, I will read up on it. Is there another way to initialize the delegate?

Comment: Relationship segues *do* get handled in `prepare(for: segue ... )`. Giving the tabBarController -> viewController segue an identifier and handling it in the TabBarController should work if you actually want to pass data from a TabBarController to a ViewController.

In this case, they're passing data between 2 `UIViewControllers` embedded in a `UITabBarController`